# Memcache php cli vs apache using different caches?

Tags: php, apache, memcached, command-line-interface

Tried to find this answer all over, but hitting a wall.

Code: (saved as recent.php)

```
$MEMCACHE_SERVERS = array(
    "1.2.3.4", //db prodmaster
    "5.6.7.8",  //db prodslave1
    "9.10.11.12" //db1 dev
);

$memcache = new Memcache();
foreach($MEMCACHE_SERVERS as $server){
    $memcache->addServer($server,11211);
}
$key = "rec_obj_".$cat_id;
$memcache->delete($key);
$memcache->set($key, $objects, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, $time=60*60*4);
```

Given above code, why does it access different caches when running from cli vs. apache? When I run php /var/www/localhost/htdocs/url/recent.php from command line, it runs perfectly but I cannot then retrieve the data from my website via $memcache->get($key).
Vice-versa, when I run the same script from web browser http://www.url.com/recent.php it runs perfectly but it cannot be found from command line? Command line memcache results can be found via $memcache->get($key) run in command line, web browser results can be found via $memcache->get($key) from web broswer. CLI and Web caches seem to be separate, how can I fix that?

I have check my phpinfo(), both php-apache2 and php-cli have extension=memcache.so. Also, I thought it might be hash difference, but both say:

```
Directive               Local Value Master Value
memcache.allow_failover 1   1
memcache.chunk_size 8192    8192
memcache.default_port   11211   11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms 1000    1000
memcache.hash_function  crc32   crc32
memcache.hash_strategy  consistent  consistent
memcache.max_failover_attempts  100 100
```

Have also tried outputting status and checking $memcache->getExtendedStats(); from both command and web browser. Both show all 3 servers. Some of the values are different though, like curr_items or reclaimed but off by 10 or so.

Feel like I'm missing something.. I could make a work-around and just save the data into a MySQL table, but that won't answer the question of why this is happening.

I've tried to provide all the info I think is needed, but feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: assume $cat_id is a provided integer. Same in both environments and not the issue.

Comment: What happens if you tell it to use only one of the three servers?

Comment: Good catch, when only using 1 server, it appears to work. Narrows it down to either allocating slabs different in cli vs apache or one is failing to access all 3 servers correctly. I'll look into this. Thanks for the leg up.

Comment: It might be even more insidious than that.  Try using each of the servers independently, maybe one is doing something incorrect all of the time.  Glad this helped!

Comment: Are the servers added in the same order? That seems to make a difference (I tend to just sort IP's alphabetically before calling `addServer`...).

Comment: Make me understand better... what you say is that your memcached client doesn't connect to all 3 memcached servers?

Comment: Command line uses a differente php.ini file, maybe there's something there ...

Answer (score 1):

When you run CLI PHP, you run it as your user.  When you access it through Apache, it runs as the apache user (www-data or similar).  memcached actually cares about your username, it will create different caches for different users.  So you have two completely separate caches.

You can list these caches using `sudo ipcs` on Linux, look under `Shared Memory Segments`.  Check out the "owner" column, you'll likely see both.  I personally resolve this by running my CLI PHP as the www-data user:

```
sudo su www-data -c "php lawl.php"
```

Comment: Gremlins? :) I had the same problem except I couldn't get it to work with even 1 server.  The easy explanation is "my answer is wrong", but I'd want to see the output of `ipcs`; it's too perfectly like my problem for me to easily believe it's not the same problem. :)